# Accessing members of a struct reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, reference

I have passed a reference of a struct to my function and need to access one of the members and pass it by reference to another function but it doesn't work. I am quite new to C++ so am not so familiar with the ins and outs of pointers yet. The important parts of my code:

```
// uses VEXcode API https://api.vexcode.cloud/v5/
// also excuse the odd color vs colour naming: I am British but the API is American. For clarity,
// "color" is a type but "colour" is a name

typedef struct {
    // other members
    color colour,
} autonButton;

const autonButton auton1{
    // other members
    .colour = color::blue,
};

void drawButtonSlot(autonButton& button) {
    // other code
    Brain.Screen.setFillColor(&button.colour);    // MY PROBLEM
    // other code
};

drawButtonSlot(&auton1);
```

The function `setFillColor` takes a `color&` type but when I pass the member like above it renders an odd shade which is not the colour blue.

I have tried to change the `&button.colour` to `button.colour` but that results in no colour being rendered.

If I change the `color::blue` to `color::green` it still gives me the same wrong shade.

My only guess is that it is reading a pointer as if it is a color type and giving the wrong shade although I don't know if this is correct nor how to fix this.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: References are reference.  Pointer are pointers.  References are not pointers.  Pointers are not references.

Comment: Why do you pass setFillColor reference of colour? And what is the definition of setFillColor ?

Comment: Just remove all of the `&` in your expressions. `&` in an expression is to form a pointer, but there are not supposed to be any pointers in your code. And then `auton1` is marked `const`, so you can't pass it to functions that want a non-`const` reference.

Comment: @CemPolat The VEXcode API (https://api.vexcode.cloud/v5/) I am using defines setFillColor and requires a &color type as an argument.

Comment: Also `typedef struct { /*...*/ } autonButton;` is C syntax that's pointless in C++. Just write `struct autonButton { /*...*/ };`.

Comment: @M.W `&color` is not valid syntax for a type. I think you mean `color&`, which would be a reference-to-`color` type.

Comment: `color colour,` is also a syntax error.

Comment: @M.W as others already told, you should remove & at setFillColor call. If a method has a reference parameter in it's definition, you don't put to the parameter when you call the method

Comment: `void drawButtonSlot(autonButton& button) {` -> `void drawButtonSlot(const autonButton& button) {` and `drawButtonSlot(&auton1);` -> `drawButtonSlot(auton1);`

Comment: If you're new to C++ here is some resources to learn C++ from : a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C"). Or you can use  [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/). Also make sure to check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
And finally refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to learn how C++  is intended to be used according to the latest insights

Comment: If you look at the (numerous) overloads of the `setFillColor()` method, it is very likely that your incorrect use of pointers is misinterpreted and mismatched against the `const char*` version or the templated version of the function. At which point the behavior is (kind of) undefined. Unfortunately, the API you are using is ill-designed, because it provides very little compile-time protection against errors of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass a pointer to a function that takes a reference.

```
typedef struct {
    // other members
    color colour,
} autonButton;

const autonButton auton1{
    // other members
    .colour = color::blue,
};

void drawButtonSlot(const autonButton& button) {
    // other code
    color c = button.colour;
    Brain.Screen.setFillColor(c); // Since you said setFillColor takes a reference, don't pass an address
    // other code
};

drawButtonSlot(auton1); // Since drawButtonSlot takes a reference, don't pass its address
```

Comment: This is what I tried originally and it still didn't work. Maybe it has something to do with how, in my full code, I am iterating through an array of `autonButton`s using `for (autonButton b: buttons) { drawButtonSlot(b); }`